# React Js, Node Js and MySQL website data does not pass to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, database, api

hello i am creating an webiste using react node and mysql and i have created a admin signup and login page **but when i tried login it does not log into the website or shows any errors **

i am using mamp server to connect to the mysql database

i have provided the screenshots and codes of my work

mysq1 databse

[image]

i have manually added the value to try wather the login is working

app.js

```
import './styles/App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Routes, Route, Outlet} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home';
import Contact from './Pages/Contact/Contact';
import Products from './Pages/Products/Products';
import About from './Pages/About/About';
import Login from "./Admin/login/Login";
import Signup from "./Admin/signup/Signup";
import AdminPanel from "./Admin/AdminPanel";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
                <Route path="products" element={<Products/>}/>
                <Route path="contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
                <Route path="about" element={<About/>}/>
                <Route path='login' element={<Login/>}/>
                <Route path='signup' element={<Signup/>}/>
                <Route path='adminPanel' element={<AdminPanel/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost" / "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "admin",
});

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const sql = "INSERT INTO login (`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (?)";
  const values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password];

  db.query(sql, [values], (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json("Error");
    }
    return res.json(data);
  });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT * FROM 'login' WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
  const values = [req.body.email, req.body.password];
  db.query(sql, values, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json("Error");
    }
    if (data.length > 0) {
      return res.json("Success");
    } else {
      return res.json("Invalid username or password");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(880, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 880");
});
```

login.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Validate from "./LoginValidation";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [event.target.name]: [event.target.value],
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(Validate(values));
    if (errors.email === "" && errors.password === "") {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:880/login", values)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data === "Success") {
            navigate("/adminPanel");
          } else {
            alert("Invalid email or password");
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="background">
      <div className="admin-login">
        <h2 className="admin-login-heading">Admin Login</h2>
        <form action="" className="login-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className="text-box"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          {errors?.email ? (
            <span className="errors"> {errors.email} </span>
          ) : null}
          <input
            className="text-box"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          {errors?.password ? (
            <span className="errors"> {errors.password} </span>
          ) : null}
          <button className="login-btn" type="submit">
            Login
          </button>
          <p>
            Forgot Password? <a href="">Click here</a>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

signup.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Validate from "./SignupValidation";

function Signup() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [event.target.name]: [event.target.value],
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(Validate(values));
    if (
      errors.username === "" &&
      errors.email === "" &&
      errors.password === ""
    ) {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:880/signup", values)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data === "Success") {
            navigate("/signup");
          } else {
            alert("Invalid username or password");
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="background">
      <div className="admin-signing">
        <h2 className="admin-login-heading">Admin Signup</h2>
        <form action="" className="signup-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className="text-box"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Username"
            name="username"
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          {errors?.username ? (
            <span className="errors"> {errors.username} </span>
          ) : null}
          <input
            className="text-box"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          {errors?.email ? (
            <span className="errors"> {errors.email} </span>
          ) : null}
          <input
            className="text-box"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          {errors?.password ? (
            <span className="errors"> {errors.password} </span>
          ) : null}
          <button className="login-btn" type="submit">
            Signup
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "sql": "^0.78.0"
  }
}
```

please can you help to solve this

i tried changing from mamp server to xammp server but it did not resolve